# Changes in import statement python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand the following from [pep-0404](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/)

> In Python 3, implicit relative imports within packages are no longer
>   available - only absolute imports and explicit relative imports are
>   supported. In addition, star imports (e.g. from x import *) are only
>   permitted in module level code.

What is a relative import?
In what other places star import was allowed in python2?
Please explain with examples.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

Relative import happens whenever you are importing a package relative to the current script/package.

Consider the following tree for example:

```
mypkg
├── base.py
└── derived.py
```

Now, your `derived.py` requires something from `base.py`. In Python 2, you could do it like this (in `derived.py`):

```
from base import BaseThing
```

Python 3 no longer supports that since it's not explicit whether you want the 'relative' or 'absolute' `base`. In other words, if there was a Python package named `base` installed in the system, you'd get the wrong one.

Instead it requires you to use *explicit imports* which explicitly specify location of a module on a path-alike basis. Your `derived.py` would look like:

```
from .base import BaseThing
```

The leading `.` says 'import `base` from module directory'; in other words, `.base` maps to `./base.py`.

Similarly, there is `..` prefix which goes up the directory hierarchy like `../` (with `..mod` mapping to `../mod.py`), and then `...` which goes two levels up (`../../mod.py`) and so on.

Please however note that the relative paths listed above were relative to directory where current module (`derived.py`) resides in, *not* the current working directory.

---

*@BrenBarn* has already explained the star import case. For completeness, I will have to say the same ;).

For example, you need to use a few `math` functions but you use them only in a single function. In Python 2 you were permitted to be semi-lazy:

```
def sin_degrees(x):
    from math import *
    return sin(degrees(x))
```

Note that it already triggers a warning in Python 2:

```
a.py:1: SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level
  def sin_degrees(x):
```

In modern Python 2 code you should and in Python 3 you have to do either:

```
def sin_degrees(x):
    from math import sin, degrees
    return sin(degrees(x))
```

or:

```
from math import *

def sin_degrees(x):
    return sin(degrees(x))
```

Comment: This of course fails when one runs `python derived.py`

Comment: @MiloBem yep, so what do you do if you need both cases to work?

Comment: Following this paradigm just results in an import error. My IDE can see what I'm trying to do based on autocomplete working correctly, but Python doesn't care for it.

Answer (score 15):

For relative imports see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references).  A relative import is when you import from a module relative to that module's location, instead of absolutely from `sys.path`.

As for `import *`, Python 2 allowed star imports within functions, for instance:

```
>>> def f():
...     from math import *
...     print sqrt
```

A warning is issued for this in Python 2 (at least recent versions).  In Python 3 it is no longer allowed and you can only do star imports at the top level of a module (not inside functions or classes).

Comment: Why was that decision made?

Comment: My guess is that idea behind it is 'Explicit is better than implicit.' from PEP20 - The Zen of Python. Dot before module makes relative/nonrelative linking explicit thus resolving possible name collisions. Although 'Readability counts.' suffers slightly.

Comment: No, in fact it was the "opposite", "practicality beats purity" decision. That was necessary in order to optimize local variable access inside functions, since without "import *", compiler always knows just by analyzing the code, what variables are local and can be looked up directly. In fact, functions don't even use a dict for local storage, but an optimized array where variables get unique indices.

Answer (score 15):

To support both Python 2 and Python 3, use explicit relative imports as below. They are relative to the current module. They have been supported [starting from 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references).

```
from .sister import foo
from . import brother
from ..aunt import bar
from .. import uncle
```

Comment: import .brother gives me an invalid syntax error in Python 3.5. This is normal? I have _init_.py in the directory it is in

Comment: `import .brother` is invalid syntax for both python 2 and 3

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe and so seems to be `import ..uncle`. Fixed. Oh, what have I been thinking... probably got distracted by the knights who say Ni!

Answer (score 4):

Added another case to Michał Górny's answer:

Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always "`__main__`", modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application must always use absolute imports.

Comment: This is wrong.  Relative imports are based off of `__package__`.  And the module level `__package__` attribute is writable, so even when `__name__ == "__main__"` [you can specify where you want relative imports to resolve by setting a `__package__` attribute](https://tio.run/##Tcw9DoAgDEDhnVM0TLK4OHuWpuFHidASrIOnRxMXx/cNr926Cy9jtJ5ZJ0SmGhGdQWzkD9regBWsl1Ki1yx8WpO6VJgh1yZdIcREV9GQvZrv8hM3xgM).