# Python ImportError: No module named 'xxxx'

Tags: python, importerror, import

Getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python33/Lib/123.py", line 5, in <module>
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
File "C:/Python33/lib/site-packages/wordpress_xmlrpc/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
import base
ImportError: No module named 'base'
```

base.py is located in:

```
C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\wordpress_xmlrpc\
```

__init__.py looks like:

```
from base import *
from wordpress import *
import methods
```

All other imports I use work fine.

Path variables look like:

```
C:\Python33;C:\Python33\Scripts;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\wordpress_xmlrpc;C:\Python33\Lib;
```

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Comment: Your own application wouldn't happen to change the path variables run-time, would it?

Comment: from foo import * is usually frowned on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either explicit relative or absolute  imports when you use python3, so

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import base
# or
from . import base
```

In python3 `import base` would only import an absolute package `base`, as implicit relative imports are no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports are  used with a "." when using python 3.

Please see the already ansewred question

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)

Comment: Relative imports _are_ permitted in py3, just not _implicit_ relative imports. You need the explicit form (`from . import ...`)