# How did importing work inside a package module work in Python 2.7.x and why/how has it change in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Consider the following directory structure

```
driver.py
m/__init__.py
m/bar.py
m/foo.py
```

With the following contents

`driver.py:`

```
import m.foo
print("Hello world!")
```

`m/__init__.py: FILE IS EMPTY`

`m/bar.py:`

```
print("I am bar")
```

`m/foo.py:`

```
import bar
print("I am foo")
```

Running `python2 driver.py` works, running `python3 driver.py` does not work (ImportError in m/foo.py trying to import bar) which leads me to ask several questions.

1. How did importing inside module that is inside a package work in Python 2.7 work? What is clear to me is, if I do a module import inside `driver.py` (e.g. `import m.foo`) AFAIK this will search for the module in the `sys.path` list that belongs to `__main__` (in this case `driver.py`). What is not clear however is what happens when a module that `driver.py` imports does an import itself (e.g. `m/foo.py` tries to import `m/bar.py`). It appears that `sys.path` in `m/foo.py` is identical to `sys.path` in `driver.py` so I do not understand how Python 2.7 successfully does `import bar` when the `m/` directory is not in `sys.path`.
2. What changed between Python-2.7 and Python-3.x? It seems that I have to do

`from . import bar`

instead of

`import bar`

inside `m/foo.py` for this trivial example to work under Python-3.x

UPDATE:
It seems [PEP328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) is the reason for the change.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changes in import statement python3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)

Comment: @jonrsharpe : The question you link to basically answers my second question **but** not the first.

Comment: To answer the first question, the default CPython implementation will also look for files inside the current working directory to import files. Which is why the files m/foo.py and m/bar.py could have relative imports.