# Creating (not distributing) and importing Python 3.3/4 packages vs Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import, package

Okay, so in the past, I've made my own `Python packages` with `Python 2.x` (most recently, `2.7.5`). It has worked fine. Let me explain how I did that, for reference:

1. Make a `directory` within the working directory. We'll call it `myPackage`.
2. Make a file called `__init__.py` in the directory `myPackage`.
3. Make sure all the modules that you want to be part of the package are imported within `__init__.py`. These modules are typically in the myPackage folder.
4. From a `Python` program in the working directory, type import myPackage (and it imports fine, and is usable).

However, in `Python 3`, I get errors with that. (`ImportError: No module named 'Whatever the first imported module is'`)

I researched the problem and found the following:

- Starred imports don't work in `Python 3.3`.
- The `__init__.py` file is not required in `Python 3.3`.

So, I removed the stars from my imports, and leaving the `__init__.py` file in, I still got errors (`ImportError: No module named 'Whatever the first imported module is'`). So, I removed the `__init__.py` file, and I don't get any errors, but my package doesn't include any of my modules.

Okay, so I discovered by doing a web search for `python3 __init__.py` or some such that I can do the following, although I don't have any clue if this is the standard way of doing things:

In the modules in the package, make sure there are no plain imports (not just no starred ones). Only do `from myModule import stuff`. However, you need to put a `.` in front of `myModule`: e.g. `from .myModule import stuff`. Then, I can `import myPackage.oneOfMyModules`

I found that by following this rule in the `__init__.py` file, it also works.

Once again, I don't know if this is how it's supposed to work, but it seems to work.

I found this page that is supposed to have something to do with the changes in packages in Python 3.something, but I'm not sure how it relates to what I'm doing:

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/

So, what is the standard way to do this? Where is it documented (actually saying the syntax)? Is the way I'm doing it right? Can I do regular imports instead of `from package import module`?

After analyzing some Python 3 packages installed on my system (I should have tried that to start with!) I discovered that they often seem to do things a little differently. Instead of just doing `from .myModule import stuff` they would do `from myPackage.myModule import stuff` (inside the modules in the package). So, that works, too, I suppose, and seems to be more frequently used.

Comment: Read the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12172791/205580), which describes explicit relative imports. Also read [PEP 328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328).

Comment: Thanks. That's quite useful. I'd give you a plus 1 if it were an answer instead of a comment (and if I had the privileges to do so: I'm still new here). It's good to know I can use multiple `.` characters to go up directories. I'm still wondering if I did it entirely right, though. Analyzing the actual files where someone has made a package would be quite helpful. Maybe I'll try that.