# Import submodule from another one

Tags: python, module

I though it was easy, but I just can't do it.
I read in [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) that this should work :

#### File `a/__init__.py`

```
 #nothing here
```

#### File `a/b.py`

```
var = "hello world"
```

#### File `a/c.py`

```
import b
print(b.var)
```

From `.` :

```
>>> import a.c
ImportError: No module named 'b'
```

But it does not… What have I forgotten ? Is it because I use Python 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's because of Python3.

```
In Python 3, implicit relative imports within packages are no longer available
```

[Changes in import statement python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)

Comment: So what is the common way to do so ? Actually I want a special submodule to load in each other submodules. Maybe there is something more idiomatic for that ?

Comment: you should explicitly specifiy that you want relative import - `from . import b`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind that, I believe you should save your file in Program Files (x86)/Lib to create a new module, well that is for Python 2.7.6, but it is very possible it will work too for Python 3.0.

Comment: Srsly I don't think so. Creating a module is as simple as creating a file (actually it is all the same). Creating a package is a little bit more complex but should be easy too… Except here !