# Python3 correct way to import relative or absolute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, import, package

I am writing a python module *neuralnet*. It was working all fine in Python2, but in Python3 imports are failing.

This is my code structure.

```
neuralnet/
    __init__.py
    train.py         # A wrapper to train (does not define new things)
    neuralnet.py     # Defines the workhorse class neuralnet
    layer/
        __init__.py
        inlayer.py       # Defines input layer class
        hiddenlayer.py

application/         # A seperate application (not part of the package)
   classify.py       # Imports the neuralnet class from neuralnet.py
```

`train.py` needs to import neuralnet.py's `neuralnet` class.

`neuralnet.py` needs to import `layers/inlayer.py` etc.

(I prefer relative imports.)

I have a different application (`classify.py`) which needs to import this module.
Where I do...

```
from neuralnet.neuralnet import neuralnet
```

I have tried a few ways to import.
Either I get an error (mostly arcane like parent is not imported)

1. While running train.py (which is a part of the neuralnet module)

   ```
   from . import layer  # In file neuralnet.py
   SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
   ```

Or

2. while running classify.py (which is outside the module).

   ```
   from layer.inlayers import input_layer   # In file neuralnet.py
   ImportError: No module named 'layer'
   ```

My imports worked perfectly well for years in Python2. I am wondering what Python3 expects of me? Should I move `train.py` to outside my module (technically it is not a part of the module)? Please suggest best practice.

Comment: By `net.py` do you mean `neuralnet.py`?  Your example does not include a file called `net.py`.  Also, if train.py is not part of your package, then yes, you should move it out.

Answer (score 10):

In Python 3, *implicit* relative imports are forbidden, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/ and https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax:

> The only acceptable syntax for relative imports is from .[module]
>   import name. All import forms not starting with . are interpreted as
>   absolute imports. (PEP 0328)

`from .stuff import Stuff` is an *explicit* relative import, which you "should" make use of whenever possible, and *must* use in Python 3, whenever possible. Head over to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173406/145400 for a deeper analysis on relative imports.

Comment: Nope that does not work!
`from .layer.inlayers import InputLayer`
throws
`SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Comment: You really should get your question cleaned up first (it still refers to a net.py). Then, make sure you are making proper use of `__init__.py`. In there, you specify the public interface of a package. That is, in `neuralnet/__init__.py` you better import everything relevant relatively, and control via `__all__` what should be exposed to the outside. Same with your layers package. The neuralnet package should import from layers only those entities you explicitly expose in `layers/__init__.py`.

Comment: Well, implicit absolute imports aren't exactly *forbidden*. They simply *don't exist*.

Answer (score 2):

Relative import usage has changed from python2 to python3,

> The only acceptable syntax for relative imports is `from .[module] import name`. All import forms not starting with . are interpreted as absolute imports. (`PEP 0328`)

> Python’s `-m` switch allows running a module as a script. When you ran a module that was located inside a package, relative imports didn’t work correctly.
> The *fix for Python 2.6* adds a `__package__` attribute to modules. When this attribute is present, relative imports will be relative to the value of this attribute instead of the `__name__` attribute. (`PEP 0366`)

## To your questions:

1. You get `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` or
   in Python3.5 and forward you would get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` when
   you run `python neuralnet.py` and try to import `from . import layers` as your `__package__` would be `None` and PYTHONPATH will only have current file(and not its parent), hence it can't find `layer`.

**You may either run the module like this:**

```
python -m neuralnet.neuralnet
```

Here your `__package__` will be `neuralnet`, hence you will be able to import the `neuralnet` module which is within it.

Or **you may do this workaround:**

Update the `__init__.py` in `neuralnet` package to:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Then run your script `neuralnet.py`, the above lines will add `neuralnet` directory to the PYTHONPATH.

2. You get `ImportError: No module named 'layer'` when `layer` is not a module that is in your PYTHONPATH so **either install it** or **add it to the PATH** using

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append("/path/to/layer")
   ```

---

### Background:

Part of a message from Guido(author of Python):

> ... in 2.4, we introduce the leading dot notation for relative import,
> while still allowing relative import without a leading dot.  In
> 2.5 we can start warning about relative import without a leading dot
> (although that will undoubtedly get complaints from folks who have
> code that needs to work with 2.3 still).  **In 3.0 we can retire ambiguous import.**

> The use case for multiple dots should be obvious: inside a highly
> structured package, modules inside one subpackage must have a way to
> do relative import from another subpackage of the same parent package.

> There is the remaining issue of what exactly the syntax would be.  I
> propose to extend the from clause to allow one or more dots before the
> dotted name, and to make the dotted name optional if at least one
> leading dot is found.  I propose not to change from-less import.

> Examples:
>
> ```
>   from .foo import bar
>   from .foo.bar import xxx
>   from . import foobar as barfoo
>   from ..foo.bar import *
>   from ... import foobar, barfoo
> ```

Relavent PEP to read: [PEP-328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#relative-imports-and-name)