# relative import in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Say my project is structured like this:

```
myproject
├── calendar.py
├── foo.py
└── __init__.py
```

In foo.py, I have

```
from calendar import isleap
```

I thought in Python 3.x, without using the explicit ***.calendar*** the code above should load the build-in calendar module instead my own calendar module, but apparently my local calendar.py is still being imported and it throws an error because there's no 'isleap' in mypkg/calendar.py. Why was my local calendar module imported here?

I had to rename calendar.py to cal.py to get this work..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is..why is my local calendar module being loaded?

Comment: Because that is the first location that a module is being searched in.

Comment: That's normal. Python load the local module first.

Comment: @julivico  Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3 seems to suggest you have to use .calendar for local module  ..Is it possible to let it load build-in module first?

Comment: Yes, it's suggested to use `from .calendar import isleap`. But `from calendar import isleap` will do **fast** the same thing.

Comment: @julivico ah..thanks..I was under the impression that the explicit import *requires* to use .calendar for the local module and without it it goes the build-in.. just my own imagination I suppose! :)  I'm guessing the sensible way to solve this is to rename my module then..

Comment: related: [Relative imports in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/4279)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 correct way to import relative or absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400690/python3-correct-way-to-import-relative-or-absolute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`from __future__ import absolute_import`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports) is the default on Python 3. Therefore `from calendar import isleap` statement imports the top-level module `calendar`.

If you see other results; it means either you are not using Python 3 or you are trying to run a python module from inside a package as a script (`myproject` directory itself is in `sys.path`). If the latter then your `calendar.py` becomes the top-level module and (due to the current directory comes before stdlib directories in `sys.path`) `from calendar import isleap` imports `calendar.py` from the current directory. ["Never add a package directory, or any directory inside a package, directly to the Python path"](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap)

To avoid it, do not run modules from within python packages directly e.g., do not do this: `cd myproject; python foo.py`. Do this instead: `python -mmyproject.foo` (or you could [define what scripts should be run in `setup.py`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) or [create a similar script manually: `from myproject import foo; foo.main()`](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#command-line-scripts)).

If you want to run a Python package as a script then create `myproject/__main__.py` then run `python -mmyproject`.

---

If you want to do a relative import in Python 3; do it explicitly e.g., in `myproject/foo.py`:

```
from .calendar import something
```

Or do an absolute import:

```
from myproject.calendar import something
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your path or directory structure is set up wrong.

Given the following structure the full name of your calendar module should be `myproject.calendar`. You can check this by printing out the `__name__` attribute of your module. For this to be the case, the path that your program uses to import local modules must be the folder containing `myproject`.

```
myproject
├── calendar.py
├── foo.py
└── __init__.py
```

It seems like the path you are using is actually `myproject`. Meaning `calendar.py` is turned into the root level module `calendar`, rather than `myproject.calendar`. Python prefers local modules to builtin ones, and so imports your `calendar` module.

More typically you might do something like this.

```
MyProjectFolder
├── main.py
└── myproject
    ├── calendar.py
    ├── foo.py
    └── __init__.py
```

And then run your program like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /path/to/MyProjectFolder
python main.py
```

Answer (score -1):

Python will check your local modules and load them firstly by `import`.

`from calendar import isleap` will search the module `calendar` in your locale package firstly. If not found, it will import from the builtin library `calendar`.

`from .calendar import isleap` will only import from your locale module `calendar`. If not found, raises a exception `ImportError`.

That is why you should use relative import in a package.

You can do a trick like that to import the builtin library without checking of the local modules. But it's only a trick. I will never use it in production. You should better rename your module `calendar`.

```
import imp, sys
f, pathname, desc = imp.find_module("calendar", sys.path[1:])
calendar = imp.load_module("calendar", f, pathname, desc)
f.close()

from calendar import isleap
```