# Resolving relative function imports in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Directory is structured as follows:

```sh
superParent
│   app.py
├───custom_package
       file1.py
       file2.py
       file3.py
       file4.py
       __init__.py
```

I am running `app.py`
I want to import functions from `file1.py` and `file2.py` into `app.py`. I also import functions from `file3.py` and `file4.py` in `file1.py` and  `file2.py`.

Now when I include

```py
from custom_package.file1 import func_abc
```

in `app.py` it throws an `ModuleNotFound` error. However,

```py
from custom_package import file1
func_abc = file1.func_abc
```

works perfectly.

Similarly, when I am trying to import a function from `file3.py` into `file1.py` using:

```py
from file3 import func_efg
```

in `file1.py` it throws an `ModuleNotFound` error. However,

```py
from custom_package import file3
func_efg = file3.func_efg
```

works perfectly in `file.py`.

I have found a lot of similar questions in StackOverFlow, however, none of them addressed this peculiar (for me - not for everyone) behaviour. A lot of them suggest making changes to the `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.append('path\to\custom_package')` (while strongly arguing that we should not resort to this). How do we solve these import-related issues to import particular functions from custom-defined local packages from a relative directory (preferably without messing with `sys.path` at all)?

Additional Context (not sure if this is necessary):
I will be containerizing this and deploying the container to AKS.

Some additional StackOverflow questions which have addressed similar issues:

1. [Can't import my own modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383014/cant-import-my-own-modules-in-python)
2. [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)
3. [ImportError: No module named <something>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476403/importerror-no-module-named-something)
4. [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder/4383597#4383597)
5. [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)
6. [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)
7. [relative import in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139192/relative-import-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the leading dot format for [package relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)

And also to add your submodules (`file1`, `file2`, etc) to  `custom_package/__init__.py` as it is showed here: [submodules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules)

Comment: The leading dot format solved my issue to import functions from file3 and file4 into file1 and file2. For importing into app.py it is throwing an error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`