# Python3 relative imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-import

I'm tired of reading one-off use cases of relative imports so I figured I'd as a question to get an example of how to do a relative import from a directory **above** and **bellow**, for both importing module functions and class objects.

**directory structure:**

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── bar.py
└── src
    ├── main.py
    └── srclib
        ├── __init__.py
        └── foo.py
```

**bar.py**

```
def BarFunc():
        print("src Bar function")

class BarClass():
        def __inti__(self):
                print("src Bar Class")
        def test(self):
                print("BarClass working")
```

**foo.py**

```
def FooFunction():
        print("srclib Foo function")

class FooClass():
        def __init__(self):
                print("srclib Foo Class")
        def test(self):
                print("FooClass working")
```

**Question: What is the syntax in python 3 to import for these use cases?**

**main.py**

```
# What is the syntax to import in python 3?

# I want to be able to call FooFunc()
foo.FooFunc()

# I want to be able to create a FooClass() object
foo_class = foo.FooClass()
foo_class.test()

# I want to be able to call FooFunc()
bar.BarFunc()

# I want to be able to create a BarClass() object
bar_class = bar.BarClass()
bar_class.test()
```

Comment: Relative imports are not about directories. They are not a directory traversal mechanism; they only say which thing to import, not where in the file system that thing is located.

Comment: Okay. I did not know that. I'm still wondering how I would import my lib files from main given my directory structure though.

Comment: You cannot actually perform relative imports in `main.py` at all, as it is not part of a package.

Comment: It's impossible to import `lib.bar` in common as your top module is `main`, and `lib` is beyond top module. But you can use `sys.path.append` to add that directory or set env variable `PYTHONPATH`. Both of them are not recommended.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `def __inti__(self):` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 correct way to import relative or absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400690/python3-correct-way-to-import-relative-or-absolute)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where you start your `python` interpreter from. In your case, I would suggest you to start the interpreter from your project's root directory while making the following changes:

In file `src/srclib/__init__.py` add:

```
from . import foo
```

The reason for doing this is to explicitly state in your `__init__.py` file what to import from your module.

In your `main.py` file, add the following:

```
from lib import bar
from src.srclib import foo
```

Hope this helps!