# Relative import in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-path

I want to use relative import in Python 3.

My project:

```
main_folder
  - __init__.py
  - run.py
  - tools.py
```

I want to have in run.py (`MyClass` declared in __init__.py):

```
from . import MyClass
```

And in run.py:

```
from .tools import my_func
```

An `ImportError` is raise.

Alternatively, with absolute import, debugging in PyCharm does not work and the library takes from installed packages, not my directory.

I know one way, but it is terrible:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

How to use this import in my project?

Comment: What is the PyCharm working directory in the configuration of that run?

Comment: If you're in the directory which contains `main_folder` you can call `import main_folder.run` just fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 correct way to import relative or absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400690/python3-correct-way-to-import-relative-or-absolute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use PyCharm, it automatically makes the current module main, so relative statements like `from . import <module>` will not work. [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

to fix your problem, put the `__init__.py` and `tools.py` files in a sub-directory

```
main_directory/
    run.py
    sub_directory/
        __init__.py
        tools.py
```

in your `run.py` file, write the following as your import statements

```
from sub_directory import tools
from sub_directory.__init__ import MyClass
```

**Edit:** as @9000 mentioned, you can write `from sub_directory import MyClass` and achieve the same thing.

Comment: `from sub_directory.__init__ import MyClass` is awkward; the same effect is achieved by just `from sub_directory import MyClass`.