# How to import a package located in its parent directory using absolute import in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python package directory like this:

```
proj/
  mod_a/
    __init__.py
    x.py
    submod_x/
      __init__.py
      y.py
  mod_b/
    __init__.py
    z.py
```

with x.py:

```
import submod_x.y
```

z.py:

```
import sys, os.path
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../'))

import mod_a.x
```

Now when I run:

```
$ python2 z.py
```

I get the things done coded in y.py

But when I run:

```
$ python3 z.py
```

I got an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "z.py", line 4, in <module>
  import mod_a.x
File ".../proj/mod_a/x.py", line 1, in <module>
  import submod_x.y
ImportError: No module named 'submod_x'
```

I wonder what differences between Python 2 and Python 3 when importing a package, and how can I import a package located in its parent directory using absolute import in Python 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do this in x.py:

```
import mod_a.submod_x.y
```

Absolute imports from file locations are done with the absolute module name or like this:

```
from . import submod_x.y
```

Comment: The first option will work if `proj` is on sys.path or if `Lib/site-packages` contains a file `proj.pth` containing the absolute path of `proj`.  I do the latter at it lets me 'install' my one all-python project directory in multiple `site-packages` without copying.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for User's help.
After reading PEP carefully I am able to answer the question myself now.

Firstly, there are 3 kinds of imports that I need to know:

1. Absolute imports.

   ```
   import sys
   ```

   Here, "sys" is a module or package name reachable from sys.path($PATH). Python inserts the directory where the script lies to sys.path by default. In other words, if I run `python3 mod_b/z.py` under `proj/`, python will insert `proj/mod_b/` to sys.path.
2. Explicit relative imports.

   ```
   from ..mod_a import x
   ```

   Imports a module relative to current module(possibly *not* current working directory $PWD). The rationale is quite clearly described in [python3 doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). And there are some examples from [PEP-0328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision).

   **Attention**: explicit relative imports must always use `from <> import <>`.
3. Implicit relative imports.

   ```
   import submod_x.y
   ```

   In python2, such an import statement will lead to an import relative to current module implicitly. i.e. If I run `python2 mod_a/x.py` under `proj/`, the current module is `x`, and the module `submod_x.y` relative to `x` will be correctly imported. The statement `from submod_x import y` is equivalent to `from .submod_x import y` as the explicit relative imports mentioned above.

   However, it is obvious that implicit relative imports may be confused with absolute imports, as mentioned in [PEP-0328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports). According to [PEP-0404](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/#imports), python3 no longer supports implicit relative imports.

Secondly, running a scripts inside a package is seen an antipattern as Guido in an [email](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006793.html)...

> I'm -1 on this and on any other proposed twiddlings of the **main** machinery. The only use case seems to be running scripts that happen to be living inside a module's directory, which I've always seen as an antipattern. To make me change my mind you'd have to convince me that it isn't.

It may cause [explicit relative imports work improperly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) as you think. If you are intended to do such, refer the posts in the link above for solutions.

Here are some others' posts that may help you:

[Changes in import statement python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)

[Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)