# Relative import django models in views

Tags: python, django

May someone please give me complete explanation about how this works:

While models.py and views.py are on the same directory on a django app, why should we use relative import:

```
app1:
  models.py
    # my models was defined here

  views.py
    from .models import *      # this works
    from app1.models import *  # this also works
    from models import *       # ---this one does not work ---
```

The same will happend with admin.py

If I import

```
  from .models import *
```

Then

```
python manage.py check
```

Everything is ok
but with

```
from models import *



python manage.py check
```

`ImportError: No module named 'models`'

I'm using now python 3.4.x and I had not this problem with 2.7.x

Comment: Becuase the execution of the django application is a folder above app1.

Comment: Executing file is manage.py, so please explain where is goes and how it works?

Comment: So with .models python should found the models module in execution file parent directory? So how it will be found in app directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know what version of Python you're using, but I would guess it's Python 3. To quote PEP 8:

> Implicit relative imports should never be used and have been removed in Python 3.

I would recommend reading through the section of PEP 8 on imports, here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

And if you want to read more about the topic, I would suggest [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), which goes into far more detail about the rationale for absolute vs relative imports.

Here is an other link with a more clear description on python 3 relative imports:

[Changes in import statement python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)

Comment: I found the best answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3