# Getting ImportError when running nosetests

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose, nosetests

```
my_project
    -my_project
        - __init__.py
        - main.py
        - constants.py
        -test
            - __init__.py
            - test_main.py
```

test_main.py `from my_project import main`

main.py `import constants`

When I run nosetests in my_project, I end up getting `ImportError: No module named 'constants'`

Both `__init__.py` files are blank.

If I change `import constants` to `from my_project import constants` in `main.py`, nosetests work. However, now if I just run `python main.py` I get `ImportError: No module named 'my_project'`.

Can someone help me point out what I'm doing wrong? I've searched quite a few posts but I haven't been able to fix it myself. Thanks.

Comment: If you're not running from my_project (or its parent directory), then you need to tell Python where to look for your module.  You can add your my_project path to `sys.path` to force it to look there.

Comment: I see, but I am running `nosetests` from my_project (parent directory) and I've also tried running it in the other my_project (child) directory as well. In both cases, I end up getting `ImportError: No module named 'constants'`.

Answer (score 3):

In main.py -> `import constants` is an implicit relative import (bad).  It should be changed to the more usual `from my_project import constants`.

You mentioned this makes nosetests work.  Note: you don't need the `__init__.py` in the tests sub-directory, and in fact this is usually discouraged.

Now to fix your error with `python main.py` having an import error, well that is normal if you haven't included it in your `sys.path`.  There are various ways around this -

- execute from the project root directory (i.e. the uppermost my_project one)
- set the PYTHONPATH environment variable
- properly package and install your app using setuptools / easy_install etc

Comment: Thank you. I will avoid implicit relative imports and remove `__init__.py`from the tests sub-directory. It seems like executing from the project root directory still doesn't solve the problem. I think this is explained by [Evert's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33767277/5573312), but I'll look into it more.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting a relative import in Python 2 style in a Python 3 project: `import constants` will, in Python 3, attempt to import `constants` at the main sys.path level.

Instead, use something like

```
from . import constants
```

in main.py

See for example [PEP 404](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/#imports):

> In Python 3, implicit relative imports within packages are no longer
>   available - only absolute imports and explicit relative imports are
>   supported.

and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3).

Comment: Thank you. As I am relatively new at this, I did not know Python 3 does not  allow implicit relative imports. I will take your suggestion into consideration and will look through your provided link.