# Travis fails to import my test module in Python 3 variants

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-3.x, travis-ci

I am trying to test my application against multiple variants of Python on Travis CI. In Python 2.7, the tests pass as expected. However, in Python 3.4 I get this traceback

```
ERROR: tests.test_mymodule (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 58, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/opt/python/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 577, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/opt/python/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 32, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.test_mymodule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 312, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/opt/python/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/travis/build/MyGitHubName/mymodule/tests/test_mymodule.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mymodule import mymodule
  File "/home/travis/build/MyGitHubName/mymodule/mymodule/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mymodule import MyModule
ImportError: cannot import name 'MyModule'
```

In Python 3.5 I get this (similar, but not exactly the same as 3.4)

```
ERROR: mymodule (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: mymodule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 462, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/opt/python/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/travis/build/MyGitHubName/mymodule/mymodule/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mymodule import MyModule
ImportError: cannot import name 'MyModule'
```

My test script has the following imports:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch
from mymodule import MyModule
```

On Travis, I have attempted to run the tests via both

```
python setup.py test
```

and

```
python -m unittest discover
```

My `__init__.py` for `mymodule` looks like this:

```
from mymodule import MyModule
```

`mymodule.py` contains the `MyModule` class.

Again, these work on Python 2.7 but not 3.4 or 3.5 due to the import errors. What do I need to adjust on my imports to allow my tests to run in Python 2.7 and Python 3.4/3.5?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have project structure like this:

[image]

You will indeed get that error, because you should be more explicit about your import in python3:
[Changes in import statement python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)

So, just edit import statement in `mymodule/__init__.py` to be explicit:

`from .mymodule import MyModule`