# django module import error - python 2.7 vs python 3.4

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-models

I have installed django1.9 with python 2.7. But now I want to use it with python3.4. Hence I have modified symbolic link of python to python 3.4 like below.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python
```

Because same django works with python 2.7 and 3.4 as well so it should work. But now if I run ./mange.py runserver I am getting below error. **But with Python 2.7 the same code works properly.**

```
from Helpers import views
ImportError: No module named 'Helpers'
```

Please let me know whats wrong there? Below are the project structure.

```
myproject
   ├── myproject
   │   ├── settings.py
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   ├── urls.py   
   │   ├── wsgi.py
   │   └─── Helpers
   │         ├── views.py
   │         └── __init__.py
   └── manage.py
```

Urls.py is like below.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from Helpers import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

setting.py contains below relevant information.

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'myproject',
    ]

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    # Look for modules here as well.
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Helpers"))
```

Any idea?

Comment: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Helpers")` would normally return `myproject/Helpers` while you actually want to have `myproject/myproject/Helpers`

Comment: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject' ,"Helpers") also not helps. By the way as mentioned this code work properly with python 2.7.

Comment: btw BASE_PATH is setting.py parent directory path.

Comment: Have you tried `from .Helpers import views` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 has changed the import policy. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3).

Instead of adding `Helpers` directory to `sys.path`, add it's parent:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject'))
```

Or like @albar mentioned - use relative import:

```
from .Helpers import views
```