# Importing issue with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have a code that runs in Python 2.7 but not in 3.5 and I can't find the reason. It has to do with importing.

The root folder has a subfolder called `s`. From the root folder, I am running the script `a.py` which includes the line `from s import *`.

In the folder `s`, there is a file called `b.py` which has the import line: `from c import c`
which tries to import the class saved in `c.py` which is located in the subfolder `s` as well.

When I run the script `a.py` from the root folder, I get the `ImportError` saying "No module named `c`".

In Python 2.7 this runs without problems. Can someone please suggest what may be the issue and how this should be done differently in Python 3.5?

Comment: Interesting. The configuration you described throws an ImportError in python2, and neither throws nor loads the module c in python3 for me.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3?  It looks related (i.e., "In Python 3, implicit relative imports within packages are no longer available").

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit imports within packages are not available for Python 3, so to get this to work you will need to use an explicit relative import:

```
from .s import *
```

This should work for both Python 2 and Python 3.  This also makes your intention more clear that you want to import from a relative package, not an installed package.

Comment: Thanks so much, so simple :). I needed exactly that - the relative import stuff in p[ython 3 is a bit different. Thank you