# ImportError: No module named '_version' when importing mechanize

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, mechanize

I installed mechanize via pip and get an errer when I import the module:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jun 28 2016, 08:46:01) 
[GCC 6.1.1 20160602] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mechanize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mechanize/__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from _version import __version__
ImportError: No module named '_version'
```

The file `-version.py` is present in the site-packages directory:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mechanize
_auth.py               __init__.py           _response.py
_beautifulsoup.py      _lwpcookiejar.py      _rfc3986.py
_clientcookie.py       _markupbase.py        _sgmllib_copy.py
_debug.py              _mechanize.py         _sockettimeout.py
_firefox3cookiejar.py  _mozillacookiejar.py  _testcase.py
_form.py               _msiecookiejar.py     _urllib2_fork.py
_gzip.py               _opener.py            _urllib2.py
_headersutil.py        _pullparser.py        _useragent.py
_html.py               __pycache__           _util.py
_http.py               _request.py           _version.py
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Mechanize is also unsupported, use requests

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at [`setup.py`](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/setup.py#L38) you'll see `mechanize` is a `Python 2.x` package:

```
Programming Language :: Python
Programming Language :: Python :: 2
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.4
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.5
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
```

Apart from that, you can see in `mechanize/__init__.py` that all imports are relative:

```
from _version import __version__
```

instead of explicit:

```
from ._version import __version__
```

*[In python 3, this results in import errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)*

There's an [issue](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/issues/96) opened for `Py3` support and it lists some alternatives you could try. That, or port it :-).

Comment: I installed with `pip3`... where can I find the setup.py?

Comment: I linked the `setup.py` in the source for `mechanize`. `pip3` can still install a python 2 package. Your specific issue is relative imports here, `mechanize` seems to use *a lot* of them in its `__init__` file. In Python 3 you need to be explicit about your imports.

Answer (score 0):

it't work for me, coppy file _version to use this command

```
cp -R __version /usr/local/lib/python3.9
```

to  determine pac