# Why can't I import a module from within the same directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

If I have two python modules in a directory `main.py` and `somemodule.py`, I can import `somemodule` by using `import somemodule`.

`./
  main.py
  somemodule.py
  __init__.py`

In django application where we have `urls.py` and `views.py`, why won't `import views` work in this case? But relative import `from . import views` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of python 3 import style and is irrelevant to Django.

Read this for more details:
[Changes in import statement python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)

Comment: Didn't see the `__init__.py` file in app directory.

Comment: `__init__.py` is not python3 specific. It should be always present in every python packages.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why `import views` doesn't work. I tried putting `__init__.py` along with `main` and `somemodule`, now `import somemodule` works.

Comment: First, enter the comand `python -V` to see which version of python you're using. Then if you want your code to be both python 2 and python 3 compatible, at the top level of your code write:
`from __future__ import absolute_import`

and then import your module like this.
`from . import submodule`