# __main__.py Behavior Different Between Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I find it convenient to place my program entry point in a different file from `__main__.py`. Below are two example files located in the same package (`test_1`):

`__main__.py:`

```
import sys
from main import main as entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    script_name = sys.argv[ 0 ]

    print( "Script name: {}".format( script_name ) )

    sys.exit( entry_point( sys.argv[ 1: ] ) )
```

`main.py:`

```
import sys

def main( args = None ):
   if args is None:
       args = sys.argv[ 1 : ]

   print( "Program arguments are: {}".format( str( args ) ) )

   return len( args )
```

When invoking the script with `python3 -m test_1 1 2 3 4`, I get the following error: "ImportError: No module named 'main'", but when invoked with `python2 -m test_1 1 2 3 4` I get the expected behavior of executing the script.

Why does the importation work differently between python2 (2.7.12) and python3 (3.5.2) and what do I need to do to accomplish the behavior I am trying to achieve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3

Comment: @TavianBarnes Thank-you. I was unaware relative imports in a `__main__.py` file worked in Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 3, the `__main__.py` needs to use an explicit relative import, so `from .main import main as entry_point` instead of `from main import main as entry_point`.