# Importing a module in Python as part of a package *as well* as in a way that works stand-alone

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.5

Note: This is Python 3.5

Given some project `thing` such that:

```
   thing/
       top.py (imports bar)
       utils/
           __init__.py (empty)
           bar.py (imports foo; has some functions and variables)
           foo.py (has some functions and variables)
```

I can `import utils.bar` in **top.py**, and when running **top.py** the file **bar.py** must contain `import utils.foo` to get to **foo.py**'s code.

To run **bar.py** directly though, **bar.py** must have `import foo` instead (`import utils.foo` fails). If I make that change then **top.py** no longer works.

**How can I run top.py or bar.py and still use the same import construct in bar.py for both use cases?** I feel like I'm missing some simple step or construct, but perhaps expecting bar.py to work independently in this way is asking too much (short of conditional imports or such).

Edit: I've accepted the proper answer, **but if you still insist on doing this with some contortions, the following worked for me**:

In **bar.py**

```
try:
    import foo
except ImportError as err:
    from . import foo
```

Then you can run bar.py directly (in my case, as I develop **bar.py** I'm using some experimental code in an `if __main__` block at the bottom of the file). Once my code is well-integrated I remove the conditional and the **main** part (since it's not meant to run standalone).

Comment: Are you sure that to run top.py, you need to have the file bar.py containing `import utils.foo`? It should be working with `import foo` only.

Comment: Yes - otherwise I get an ImportError.

Comment: Ok. The issue is specific to Python3. My previous comment is relevant only for Python2.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly specific to 3, but it's constrained by it (there are likely ways to make this work for both, but it's not easy and not worth it here).

Comment: For future references: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to make sure there wasn't a way to do what I was trying to do more concisely than the conditional import I added above in the last edit. (There's no such way and that's OK.... as for Py2 vs Py3, I try to stick with Python 3 constraints whenever possible now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its typical to have all your entrypoints outside the module, than all imports can be relative. 
For example

```
thing/
    app.py
    thing/
        __init__.py
        top.py
        utils/
            __init__.py
            bar.py
            foo.py
```

And app.py can look like

```
from thing import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.main()
```

Than in top.py you have

```
from .utils import bar
```

And in bar you have

```
from . import foo
```

Or

```
from thing.utils import foo
```

Or

```
from ..utils import foo
```

So if you need two entrypoints, you can either make `app` take a command line argument for the second entry point, or you can make another file like app that imports bar

Comment: Thank you! I added an edit to my question demonstrating a way to do this via a kind of conditional import (since now I know that's the only way to coerce Python into doing this for the temporary use case I have in mind).

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html try to use import .foo and for python 3 see [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)