# Referencing a python file from a module when loaded by import_module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I want to import a module using import_module from importlib. When I do that the files I reference from my module are not found. If I import my module normally from the python shell (not using main.py) it works as expected. Also, if I add the path of MyModule.py to sys.path it works but from what I understand I'm not supposed to do that (commented out in the code below).

How can I get my referenced file to be loaded also when the module is loaded by import_module?

I have the following file structure

```
main.py
  subfolders
    folder1
      __init__.py
      MyModule.py
      hello.py
```

Contents of `main.py`

```
from importlib import import_module

modulename = 'subfolders.folder1.MyModule'
print("Import module ", modulename)
module = import_module(modulename)
m_instance = module.MyModule()

m_instance.module_hello()
```

Contents of `MyModule.py`

```
#This is the solution that works but feels wrong
#import os, sys
#sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))

from hello import hello_world

class MyModule(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Init MyModule")

    def module_hello(self):
        hello_world()
```

Contents of `hello.py`

```
def hello_world():
    print("Hello World!")
```

When I run this I get:

```
c:\git\PythonImportTest>python main.py
Import module  subfolders.folder1.MyModule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    module = import_module(modulename)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\git\PythonImportTest\subfolders\folder1\MyModule.py", line 5, in <module>
    from hello import hello_world
ImportError: No module named 'hello'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make your `subfolders` directory a package by placing an empty `__init__.py` in there. Second you need to import your `hello` module either by absolute import or relative import.

**Absolute import:**

```
from subfolders.folder1.hello import hello_world
```

**Relative import:**

```
from .hello import hello_world
```

The way you do it at the moment will look for hello.py in your top-level package (where your main.py is). As it can not be found there you get an error.

**Note on relative imports in Python3**

You propably switched from Python2 to Python3 which is why you get in trouble when using implicit relative imports. As [PEP404](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/) says:

> In Python 3, implicit relative imports within packages are no longer
>   available - only absolute imports and explicit relative imports are
>   supported. In addition, star imports (e.g. from x import * ) are only
>   permitted in module level code.

Meaning your code should work on Python2 but for Python3 you have to use one of the above options. See also: [Changes in import statement python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your code is that subfolders is a folder and not a package. if you are using import_module it is only possible to search in packages for subpackages.

Solution:
Create a **init**.py in your subfolders folder and import folder1 there.