# python3 ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04

I work in Ubuntu16.04 x64 use python3.5 IDEA
but I got a strange question as in picture,I try rename connect,but it can't work.

How should I solve this problem? Please tell me if you known,thinks.

[image]

Comment: Is your `PYTHONPATH` env variable set to the parent of directory of `tpymysql`?

Comment: I think should't this,because I new package in same project can work but only  it can't work ,thank you ten same to you

Comment: Where is the file that contains the `import` statement in relation to `connect.py`?

Comment: in my picture,it is contains in tmysql package

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
from .tpymysql import connect
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer.  And see [Changes in import statement python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3) for background

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something like`class Connect()` in your `connect.py`.

If the script to be executed is under the same path to `connect.py`

`from connect import Connect`

Else

`from tpymysql.connect import Connect`

The Pythonic way is making everything clear and specific. So when you want to import something, import what's inside other than the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 usually throws this ImportError for relative imports. Seems relative imports are not necessary.

Try:

> import tpymysql