# change in import in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, import, python-import

I am using python 3.4.4 and testing "init.py" feature by creating a sample package But unable to implement. The mentioned case is working perfectly in case of python 2.7.13 version. Can anyone tell me the mistake i am doing or is there any change in syntax of python 3.x versions. Please help me to learn Python 3?

**Dir Structure:**

```
TestPackage/
    __init__.py
    TestModule.py
run.py
```

**Content of TestModule.py :**

```
def TestFun():
    print("Welcome")
```

**Content of __init__.py :**

```
from TestModule import TestFun
```

**Content of run.py :**

```
from TestPackage import TestFun
TestFun()
```

**When i execute run.py file, i got the following error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\CASE03\run01.py", line 1, in <module>
    from TestPackage import TestFun
  File "D:\CASE03\TestPackage\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from TestModule import TestFun
ImportError: No module named 'TestModule'
```

But when i use python 2.7.13 it works perfectly fine. Please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of `__init__.py`, if you change

```
from TestModule import TestFun
```

to

```
from .TestModule import TestFun
```

You'll get the expected behavior.

See: [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) (sections regarding relative imports using leading dots).

Comment: It is (a change in Python3).  ([Here's another answer regarding the change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173406/736937))

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `__init__.py` to the below code:

```
from TestPak.TestModule import TestFun
```

Comment: While this will work, it will couple the contents of the init file with the package name (which may change).  Not a huge deal, but the relative import (leading dot) exists and seems cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to set `__init__.py` as a blank file. In case you are interested in controlling what gets imported from your module when you do `from Testmodule import *`, you can include `__all__ = ['TestFun']` in `__init__.py` file.