# Within the py.test test directory for a python module, import a file for the module

Tags: python, pytest, python-module

I have a python module arranged in a directory. Call it `foo`.

Here is the file layout:

```
caller.py
foo/__init__.py
foo/bar.py
foo/test/bar_test.py
```

That is, the module is called `foo` and the code in `foo/__init__.py` gets imported when the `import foo` statement in `caller.py` gets run.

Within `foo/__init__.py`, I wish to access the contents of `bar.py`. This is done with `import foo.bar`.

My problem arises when writing the code that runs in `foo/test/bar_test.py`. If this file was simply `foo/bar_test.py`, then it could also use `import foo.bar` to import the contents of `foo.bar.py`. Unfortunately, we have a coding standard that says that unit tests go in a subdirectory called `tests`.

Given that coding standard, how do we import bar.py?

This doesn't work:

```
# foo/test/bar_test.py
import foo.bar
def test_return5():
   assert bar.return5() == 5
```

It gives me:

```
$ py.test
================================================== test session starts ==================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/hadoop/xxx/foo, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors

======================================================== ERRORS =========================================================
___________________________________________ ERROR collecting test/bar_test.py ___________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/hadoop/xxx/foo/test/bar_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test/bar_test.py:3: in <module>
    import foo.bar
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================================================ 1 error in 0.10 seconds ================================================
```

This works, but it's gross:

```
# foo/test/bar_test.py

import os
import sys

sys.path.append( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../.."))

import foo.bar

def test_return5():
   assert foo.bar.return5() == 5
```

This does not work:

```
# foo/test/bar_test.py

import os
import sys

sys.path.append( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))

import bar

def test_return5():
   assert bar.return5() == 5
```

Because:

```
$ py.test
================================================== test session starts ==================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/hadoop/xxx/foo, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors

======================================================== ERRORS =========================================================
___________________________________________ ERROR collecting test/bar_test.py ___________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/hadoop/xxx/foo/test/bar_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test/bar_test.py:8: in <module>
    import bar
bar.py:3: in <module>
    import foo
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================================================ 1 error in 0.10 seconds ================================================
```

Because bar.py has:

```
# foo/bar.py

import foo

def return5():
    return 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import foo.bar as bar
```

That should work in `bar_test.py` if you run pytest from the parent directory (at least, it worked for me just now).

You can't use `import bar` in python 3 (I'm assuming that's what you're using) because it's ambiguous - see [PEP-404](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/#imports) and [a more in depth stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3) for more details.

EDIT: Looking at the expanded example, it looks like the problem is that `bar_test.py` isn't part of the `foo` package (because the `test` directory isn't a package). If you add a `__init__.py` file to the `test` directory, pytest will happily run the test::

```
$ pytest foo/test/bar_test.py 
===================================================================== test session starts ======================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.3, pytest-3.6.3, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/xxxx/tmp/blank, inifile:
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                

foo/test/bar_test.py .                                                                                                                                   [100%]

=================================================================== 1 passed in 0.03 seconds ===================================================================
$ ls -lh foo/test/
total 12K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx xxxx   95 Jul 26 14:44 bar_test.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx xxxx    0 Jul 27 16:38 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx xxxx  132 Jul 27 16:38 __init__.pyc
drwxrwsr-x 2 xxxx xxxx 4.0K Jul 27 16:38 __pycache__
```

Note that I had to delete the `__pycache__` after adding `__init__.py`.

See the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-as-part-of-application-code) for more information.

Comment: It worked when I ran the tests in the foo directory, as well as in the parent directory.

Comment: Okay. It didn't work for me.  I'll put together a clear example and get it posted tonight, then we can debug. It's probably me.

Comment: Glad to hear it! It's probably worth adding what the problem was, in case someone else comes across this looking for help.

Comment: Okay. If you don't object, I'll significantly expand your answer.

Comment: Good idea - no objections from me. :)

Comment: Okay, I found the problem I'm having. The problem is doing the import from a test/ directory. I'll post the improved example tonight.

Comment: I significantly changed the example, and it shows the problem now.

Comment: No, I'm still getting `No module named 'foo'` with the `import foo.bar as bar`.

Comment: Did you delete the `__pycache__` directory in the `test` directory?