# Explicit relative imports within a package not using the keyword from

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have the following package structure:

```
mypkg
├── mymodule
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ...
├── mylib.py
└── script.py
```

In `script.py` I can do `from .mymodule import X` and `from .mylib import Y` and works fine for both Python 2 and Python 3.

In Python 2, I can do `import mymodule` and `import mylib` and it works fine and then later I can do `mymodule.X` or `mylib.Y`.

In Python 3, I cannot do `import .mymodule` nor `import .mylib` (syntax error) and if I remove the leading dot I get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule'` and  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib'`.

After reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3) I understand that I need the leading dot but why am I getting a syntax error? How can I get these imports working for both Python 2 and 3?

*Update*:
For future reference, my package structure now is:

```
mypkg
├── __init__.py
├── mymodule
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ...
├── mylib.py
└── script.py
```

Comment: `from . import mymodule`?

Comment: @zvone that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
from . import mymodule
```

and

```
from . import mylib
```

Explicit relative imports *must* use `from` syntax. The design intent is that whatever comes after the `import` in `import ...` or `from ... import ...` is a valid expression to access the imported thing after the import, and `.mymodule` is not a valid expression.

Comment: Got it. Added a `__init__.py` at the top of the package and worked like a charm. Thanks.