# In Python 3.5, can't import zenity

Tags: python, python-3.x, zenity

Python 3.5.2, Mint Linux 32-bit.

I've followed the documentation here -- https://pypi.org/project/python-zenity/#example -- and tried variations thereof, BUT cannot import the *zenity* library into Python 3.

1. `pip3 search zenity` **RESULT:**

   `python-zenity (0.1.3) - Simple dialog with Python and Gtk`
2. `sudo -H pip3 install python-zenity` **RESULT:**

   `Collecting python-zenity
   Installing collected packages: python-zenity
     Running setup.py install for python-zenity ... done
   Successfully installed python-zenity-0.1.3`
3. `pip3 list | grep zenity` **RESULT:**

   `python-zenity                 0.1.3`
4. `python3` **RESULT:**

   `Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)`
   `[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux`
   `Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`
   `>>>`
5. `import pythonzenity` **RESULT:**

   `Traceback (most recent call last):`
   `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
   `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pythonzenity/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>`
   `from python_zenity import *`
   `ImportError: No module named 'python_zenity'`

And variations of `python-zenity`, `python_zenity`, `from pythonzenity import *` (just to try to get `import` to work), and so on.

What's the "trick" to import the `python-zenity` library that *pip3* tells me I've successfully installed?

---

**EDIT:**

Per metatoaster's answer, uninstalled *pyththon-zenity*, installed *zenipy*. `import zenipy` worked straightaway:

```
>>> import zenipy
>>> dir(zenipy)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'calendar', 'color_selection', 'entry', 'error', 'file_selection', 'message', 'password', 'question', 'scale', 'warning', 'zenipy', 'zlist']
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception message is actually generated by the package itself - its `__init__.py` define a relative import which [is no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3).  If you don't mind manually correcting the statement inside (as per the `Traceback`) `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pythonzenity/__init__.py`, change the `import *` line to:

```
 from .python_zenity import *
```

Which should trigger the imports.

Alternatively, refer to the linked Git repository which actually had a package name change and the import statements are now done via the proper relative import syntax in [the same `__init__.py` file](https://github.com/poulp/zenipy/blob/v0.1.4/zenipy/__init__.py).

The better solution is to install the current version of the package under its new name, [zenipy](https://pypi.org/project/zenipy/).

Comment: I edited my question to include that after uninstalling python-zenity and installing zenipy I was able to import zenipy straightaway...