# error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'context_locals'" occurred while import tool

Tags: python

When I import module `tool`, I get the following error message,

```
  File "/Users/bird/Desktop/various-examples-of-web-crawlers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tool/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from context_locals import app, local
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'context_locals'
```

Operating system：macOS Sierra 10.12.6

IDE: pycharm

Code:

```
import urllib.request

import urllib.parse

import re

import tool

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #引入工具类
    self_tool = tool.Tool()
```

I tried to find a solution on google, but failed.

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: The module you appear to be trying to use hasn't been maintained in over 7 years. It's a dead project, and it's incompatible with Python 3.

Comment: @Jeril

# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import tool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #引入工具类
    self_tool = tool.Tool()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and installed [the package](https://pypi.org/project/tool/) to reproduce the error.

The problem arises because the package is written for Python 2, and uses implicit local imports. They were prohibited in Python 3. Read more in this question: [Changes in import statement python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3).

But even after you fix the relative imports problems, you get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'alias' from 'argh'
```

`argh` is a dependency of `tool` and a failure to import it indicates that the wrong (more recent) version of `argh` gets installed.

At this point your options are to try and install the package with Python 2 or port it to Python 3. See [How To Port Python 2 Code to Python 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-port-python-2-code-to-python-3).