# Import Error in Python2.7 but not in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-2.x

I've got a python package written locally with a structure like

```
package
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── package_tests.py
└── package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── package.py
```

This works great when run using `python -m package` in a Python3 virtualenv from the root of the project (parent dir of the first `package` dir in that tree)

However when run in a Python2.7 virtualenv, I get an `ImportError` in the `__main__.py` script as it tries to import the functions from `package.py`

`__main__.py`:

```
import sys
from package.package.package import foo, bar


    def main(args):
        f = foo(args)
        bar(f)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The error:

`ImportError: No module named package`

What do I need to change to make it compatible with both?

(Obviously the package isn't actually called package)

Comment: have you tried to print `sys.argv` in both pythons? Is there any difference?

Comment: try to rename the inner folder package to something else, and see it it works for both

Comment: sys.argv worked fine in both versions, it was the relative imports that were the issue @OlvinRoght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite looking for an explanation for so long, immediately after posting this question I found a solution.

After looking over [the changes to imports between python 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3) I found that I only needed to use relative imports.

So the import line in my `__main__.py` became
`from .package.package import foo, bar`