# can't import a script from the same module

Tags: python-3.x

This situation may be related to python's configuration. My OS is OSX 10.14.6

Here is my directory tree:

```
code
|--- main.py
|--- module
     |--- __init__.py
     |--- core.py
     |--- util.py
```

In main.py

```
from module import core
```

In core.py

```
import util
```

This works (python2):

```
python main.py
```

And this does not:

```
python3 main.py
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module import core
  File "/code/module/core.py", line 1, in <module>
    import util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'
```

Comment: I think this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I can give you is replace

```
import util
```

with

```
from . import util
```

I think this has something to do with python3's [Implicit Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) basically making `.` it's own module as it were. That's my guess, I haven't found anything in the docs explicitly saying that.