# Python import Pillow/PIL error, cannot ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've tried everything, adding the files to my actual project, installing and reinstalling PILLOW. Right now the actual PIL file is in my project folder and I currently have the error:

File "C:\Users\crowl\Desktop\py project\PIL\Image.py", line 69, in 
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\crowl\Desktop\py project\PIL__init__.py)

I've tried to import Image, from PIL import *, from PIL.Image import core as _imaging and currently using the from PIL import Image. I managed to get it to work on another PC by just using the PIL folder with all the source code as it's a school project and now I'm at home and it doesn't seem to work.

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Try changing the name of your script to `myImage.py`

Comment: If you still have not found a solution, try adding __init__.py to the folder where Image.py is. These links will provide a more exhaustive explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3 https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html