# Why works "import file", but "from file import class" won't work?

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I have a file with name "x.py". This contains a Class "Y". 
I have a second file with name "z.py". 
x.py and z.py are in the same directory. This directoty has an empty file with name `__init__.py`

In z.py I do:

```
from x import Y
```

This brings ImportError: cannot import name Y

If I do

```
import x
```

then I have no exception but aswell nothing from x.py

What could be the problem here?

Update:
In server environment, it works. But not in local, which is Windows with sublime text. When entire code of x is in z, then it works aswell locally.

Structure is

-Folder A
---x.py with class Y inside
---z.py with (from x import Y)

Comment: What does the file structure look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3

Comment: After `import x`, does `x.Y` work? It sounds like `Y` simply doesn't exist in `x`, and `import x` works because you make no mention of `Y`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x/59432370#59432370

Comment: @EdekiOkoh it a Folder A. Therein a file x.py and a file y.py and an empty file init.py

Comment: [Please post the current directory in your question similar to David C. Bishop answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application). It may be an issue of relative vs absolute imports. Also can you confirm the class is in Folder A.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh updated initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved. The solution was:

Somewhere in my pythonpath and my already installed packages, a module had the same name as that one I wanted to import. As the interpreter first had a look into the other module, it did not find the Class I wanted to import.

The solution was simply rename the module to import and aswell the import call itself. A lot of searching for a small issue.