# Modules in the same package cannot import each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am currently using Python 3.7.

My project has the following structure:

```
runner.py
    pkg1/
        __init__.py (empty)
        mod1.py
        mod1_helpers.py
```

In mod1.py:

```
import mod1_helpers

# call some functions in mod1_helpers.py
```

In runner.py:

```
import pkg1.mod1
```

When I run runner.py, Python threw the following error:

```
File "..\pkg1\mod1.py", line 1, in <module>  
    import mod1_helpers  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1_helpers'
```

The issue resolves when I manually add the path to pkg1 to sys.path in runner.py.

Could someone please advise the proper way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changes in import statement python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3)

Answer (score 0):

Since they're in the same directory you have to prefix import of mod1_helpers with a .

try this:

`import .mod1_helpers`