# Creating package from boost::python modules

Tags: python, c++, boost-python, python-packaging

I am trying to follow the [tutorial for creating python packages from shared objects compiled from C++ via boost::python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/techniques.html#tutorial.techniques.creating_packages), but I am running into some problems I need clarification about.

Assume I have a local `$install_dir` into which I install the compiled shared objects in the form of a python package via CMake. Parallel to the tutorial liked above, my structure is:

```
$installdir/
  my_package/
    __init__.py
    module/
      __init__.py
      _module.so
```

I have added `$installdir` to my `$PYTHONPATH`.

`$installdir/my_package/__init__.py` is empty.

`$installdir/my_package/module/__init__.py` contains:

```
from _module import *
```

When I then `import my_package.module` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_module'` raised from `$installdir/my_package/module/__init__.py`.

The issue seems to be that `_module.so` is not found from `$installdir/my_package/module/__init__.py`.

**Why is the approach from the tutorial not working?**

If I add `$installdir/my_package/module` to `$PYTHONPATH` directly everything works fine, but it feels like that should not be neccessary, as `$installdir/my_package/module/__init__.py` should find `_module.so` locally.

I implemented the following portable workaround for now within `$installdir/my_package/module/__init__.py`:

```
import sys, pathlib
sys.path.insert(0,str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()))
from _module import *
```

**Bonus Question:**
Changing the file name extension from `.so` to `.pyd` breaks the import (ModuleNotFoundError) even without any packaging and `.pyd` being accessible directly via `$PYTHONPATH`. I define the extension via CMake's `SUFFIX` target property. This is obviously mostly cosmetic, but I would still like to understand the reason and how to fix it.

**Edit:**
This is Ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.8 and boost 1.71

Comment: AFAIK the pyd extension is a Windows-only thing. Since you have an .so that your Python can import, I guess you're not on Windows.

Comment: The other problem might be due to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3 | It would be really useful if you could mention at least the platform and Python version.