# Module not found error when im creating my own pypi package

Tags: python, pypi

Im creating my own simple package that i will upload on pypi that generates jokes on my native language. While creating the package I'm bugged with this error : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

Here is my folder structure :

```
Myjokes/
    myjokes/
          
           data/
               jokes.json
           utils/
               helpers.py
           __init__.py
           jokes.py
```

when i am in the `Myjokes/` directory and i run the `python -c "from myjokes import jokes"` it runs but when i run the functions inside the jokes file it displays a module not found error :  `from utils.helpers import get_jokes_by_count , get_joke_by_dialect , pinoy_jokes ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

if i go inside `myjokes/` directory which is the subdirectory of `Myjokes` i can run the `jokes.py` script via `import jokes` and everything is running. i dont know why this is happenin I'm fairly new to python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12172791/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+absolute+relative+import

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't know that your `utils/` folder is supposed to be treated like a python package unless you include an `__init__.py` in that folder as well.

Try adding a blank `__init__.py` file inside `utils/` and see if that works for you.

Comment: I recently added ```__init__.py``` but still not working