# Importing a package module, created in Pypi, results in module not found

Tags: python, import, module, package, pypi

Structure of code:

```
setup.cfg

pyproject.toml

project (a directory)
```

project directory:

```
a.py
b.py
c.py
__init__.py
```

for example, in a.py there is a line:

```
import b
```

When building the package:

```
pip install .
```

after that typing in ubuntu's terminal:

```
python

Python 3.6.9 (default, Dec  8 2021, 21:08:43)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import project
>>> dir(project)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
>>> from project import a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...(cant show this)/project/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import b
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'
```

setup config file:

```
[metadata]
name = project
version = 0.0.1
author = *****
author_email = *****
description = **********
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = **************************
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
python_requires = >=3.6
include_package_data = True
py_modules = project
package_dir =
        =project
packages = find:
install_requires =
    numpy
    pyproj
    requests
    scipy
    requests
    importlib

[options.packages.find]
where = project
```

My pyproject.toml file:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Comment: Does this also happen with a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports): `import .b`  ?

Comment: `import b` is not correct. You need `from . import b`, or even better `from project import b` where `project` is the name of your actual top-level import package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173406/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+absolute+relative+import

Comment: They are all in the same folder (project)

Comment: import .b results in "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
(if b have one line: import c)
and import project.b gives:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'c'
@r0w

Comment: or you meant: 
 import project.b
that results in another import (let's say b have 1 line with: import c, so it results in ModuleNotFoundError on c)

Comment: @sinoroc so you mean change the python code inside a to from project import b? I don't think I get what you mean

Comment: @phd already looked at the links you sent

Comment: @orielpinhas Yes. In `project/a.py` you should write `from project import b`.

Comment: @sinoroc That did the magic! Thank you so much!