# Settings file reference is not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-2to3

I'm working on migrating an exsting Python 2.7 project to Python 3.9. I'm facing a directory structure-related issue in Python 3.

My current project directory structure is:

```
├───project
│   ├───core
|       +--__init__.py
|       +--main.py
|       +--settings.py
│   ├───jobs
|       +--job.py
```

`main.py`:

```py
import settings


class Main:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=settings.B):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def start(self):
        print(self.a, self.b)
```

`job.py`:

```py
import sys
# sys.path.insert(0, '../core/')
from core.main import Main
from core import settings

main = Main(settings.A)
main.start()
```

There is no issues with this structure when Python 2.7 interpreter is used, but in Python 3.9 I see the following error when `job.py` is executed:

```
  File "project\core\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
```

The issue is fixable by uncommenting the code on line #2 of the `job.py` script, but I would like to avoid hardcoding folder values like that. I would appreciate if someone could provide an alternative approach and an explanation why it's behaving this way in the newer Python version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to ambiguity absolute import was removed in python3 for such use case. (This explains it very well: [Changes in import statement python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3))

You can use relative import for this use case maybe - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports