# how can i fix import error for git subtree

Tags: python, git, git-subtree

I'm currently researching subtree-related issues
I added the B repository as a subtree to the A repository by creating a folder named B
However, when importing modules from the subtree, I encounter import errors

The B repository has the following folder structure:
B>C
B>D

In a specific module in the C folder, I am trying to import a function called d from the **init** file in the D folder
The code in the B repository uses the import statement
"from D import d"
However, when I try to import this in the A repository, I get an import error

It seems to be a simple problem, but I'm unable to solve it

I'm looking for a solution to include only specific folders in the top-level import statements,
but I haven't found it yet
I don't think testing it later will be a suitable solution

Comment: I won't be able to help much because I do not have experience with subtrees... _but_ If you do not provide the git command and the error output in the question (please, _as text_), it will be hard for _anyone_ to be able to help at all. (oh, and welcome to SO!)

Comment: Git commands hardly help here but the directory structure and some code are needed. [Edit] and add an [mcve] please.

Comment: Also take into account the difference between absolute and relative import, explicit and implicit. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173406/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+absolute+relative+explicit+implicit+import