# Import a class from another module

Tags: python

My file structure is as below:

```
textClassification/ #  PyCharm project
    src/  #  source files
        classA.py  #  a class
        __init__.py  #  file to make class A a valid package
    api.py
```

I want to import classA in api.py

After trying a few things, I've managed to import it as below.

```
from src.classA import classA as a
```

What is the rationale behind this? Why can't I just import classA from api.py as they are both under src?

Comment: `from .classA import classA as a` should work, too.

Comment: What you try to do is called "implicit relative import" and was removed in Python 3. See answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172791/changes-in-import-statement-python3 for some explanations.

Comment: Relative imports are generally discouraged.

Comment: How did `from src.classA import classA as a` work? That would look for another package relative to `classA` that's called `src`

Comment: @Itération122442 That was the case in the original PEP8. The current version does not discourage it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`from src.ClassA` implies a another subdirectory src.

so

```
from ClassA import classA as a
```

IIRC you can also use `from .ClassA`

Comment: Relative imports are generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Typo in your import

Your Code:
`from src.ClassA import classA as A`

Your File name is classA but you are imported ClassA with capital C

Do this:
`from src.classA import classA as a`
or
`from .classA import classA as a`

Answer (score 0):

For relative imports like this it's recommended to use leading dots [PEP0328](https://peps.python.org/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision)

That would give you:

```py
from .classA import classA as a
```